# Concat two tensors of different dimensions

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, embeddings

I have two tensors. For example -

```
a = torch.randn((500, 200, 10))
b = torch.randn((500, 5))
```

I have to concat each of `b` tensor to all elements of corresponding `a` tensor i.e., each 200 tensors of `a[0]` should get concatenated with `b[0]` - final dimension should be `(500, 200, 15)`.

Without using explicit `for` loop, how can I achieve this in Pytorch efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you should repeat `b` 200 times in the appropriate dimension this way:

```
c = torch.cat([a, torch.unsqueeze(b, 1).repeat(1, 200, 1)], dim=2)
c.shape
```

As desired, the shape of the result is `torch.Size([500, 200, 15])`

Comment: Thanks. It worked!